# How to enable RyuJIT for Visual C# 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

My console project is set for 64-bit. I'm curious how to know if RyuJIT is being used or if I need to do additional setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RyuJIT is the default x64 JIT for .NET 4.6
Just target latest version of .NET in your app config $ in project settings